# How to pass a generic function as parameter to another function?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have three functions:

```
data Foo = Foo { x :: String, y :: String, z:: String }

fooZero :: Foo
fooZero = Foo "empty" "empty" "empty"

fooOne :: String -> Foo
fooOne a = Foo a "empty" "empty"

fooThree :: String -> String -> String -> Foo
fooThree a b c = Foo (doSomething a) (doSomethingElse b) (doAnotherThing c)
```

Now I want to be able to pass them (`f :: (???? -> Foo)`) in another function, to be executed only in case it is required by another expensive function (`evalSomething`):

```
bar :: Int -> Int -> (???? -> Foo) -> Int
bar a b f = if (a == b) then a
            else if (a > b) then evalSomething f -- return Int
            else a + b
```

in this way:

```
let one = "One"
let two = "Two"
let three = "Three"

bar 8 8 (fooZero)
bar 1 2 (fooOne one)
bar 5 3 (fooThree one two three)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Types of `fooZero`, `fooOne one` and `fooThree one two three` are all `Foo`. So that's the type of `f` in `bar`. `bar :: Int -> Int -> Foo -> Int`.

Comment: that functions have different signature. `Foo` is the returned type only.

Comment: You are mistaken. `fooZero`, `fooOne` and `fooThree` have different signatures. `fooZero`, `fooOne one` and `fooThree one two three` are all of type `Foo`.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if my example is enough good. What I am trying to ask, if it is possible to pass a generic function/lambda to another function to be executed only if required.

Comment: Everything is executed only if required. Haskell is a lazy language. Research what this means.

Comment: How can I pass it? Can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: Exactly as you have written. There is no special secret incantation to pass something to a function. Just replace the bar signature and try in ghci.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As n.m. said in the comments, you simply *don't need any function type at all there* – the first-order type `bar :: Int -> Int -> Foo -> Int` will do the job just fine, since you don't actually feed the `foo` functions any arguments *within `bar`* – those arguments are passed before applying `bar`, i.e. you only pass the result. Thanks to lazyness it won't matter if the `foo` functions are expensive so you'd rather not evaluate them if not needed: Haskell will make sure function results aren't evaluated if you don't actually need them!

Generally speaking, there *is* a thing that allows you to “pass generic functions as parameters” though. It's called *Rank-2 polymorphism*.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

bar :: Int -> Int -> (∀ t . Monoid t => t -> Foo) -> Int
bar a b f
  | a == b     = a
  | a > b      = f (mempty :: [])
  | otherwise  = a + b
```

(If you're not a fan of Unicode syntax, you can also write `∀` as `forall`.)
That doesn't actually seem to be what you want for your application though.

Comment: Thank you, the answer I was looking for. My example was too simple so a bit misleading

Answer (score 2):

Just declare it as:

```
bar :: Int -> Int -> Foo -> Int
bar a b f = if (a == b) then a
        else if (a > b) then evalSomething f
        else a + b
```

And call it as:

```
bar 5 3 (fooThree one two three)
```

Since Haskell is lazy, fooThree won't actually be evaluated unless it's needed inside evalSomething.